# Are the constant sequences $2^m3^n$ a complete metric space with the metric from $c$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

> Let $c$ be the space of convergent sequences over $\Bbb R$ with the $\sup$ norm.
>
> Let $X$ be the subset of constant sequences $s=2^m3^n,2^m3^n,\ldots:m,n\in\Bbb Z$, for example $s=1,1,1,1,\ldots$ with the same metric $d$ (possibly including the sequence $0,0,\ldots$).
>
> Is $X,d$ a complete metric space?

I don't really know how to tackle this.  My first thought is that since the sequences are constant, the space is no different to using the absolute value metric on singletons $2^m3^n\in\Bbb Q^+$.  My second thought is that the set $2^m3^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so this is unlikely to be a discrete space so no trivial answer is clear to me.

I tried engineering Cauchy sequences and I can easily make ones that converge to $0,0,0,\ldots$ so I think the constantly zero sequence is needed for it to be complete.  I can't really make Cauchy sequences that converge to anything other than $0$ and some element of $X$, but I can't show it's possible or impossible to create others either.

Comment: Before getting into Cauchy sequences, ask yourself this: is it even a subspace? Is it closed under scalar multiplication, for example?

Comment: @user757704 well it's clearly not so I guess I need to learn more about subspaces.

Comment: I'm actually wondering whether it meant to say a complete metric space? Because that would be a more interesting problem. Plus the notation $(X, d)$ is suggestive of this.

Comment: @user757704 thanks there are clearly some aspects of subspace and Banach spaces I'm unaware of so I've adjusted the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\{2^m3^m\mid n,m\in\Bbb Z\}\subset \Bbb R$ and consider the map $\varphi: \Bbb R\to c$, $x\mapsto (x,x,x,x,...)$. It is easy to check that the $d(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))=|x-y|$, ie the map is an isometry onto its image. As such $\varphi(A)$ will be complete if and only if $A$ is complete.

That $A$ is complete, is not true. There are likely many reasons why $A$ is not complete, for example one can see that there is a sequence $x_n\in A$ with $x_n\to 5$ but $5\notin A$. The statement $5\notin A$ is elementary, while the construction of such a sequence follows by noting that $\{\lfloor m\log_2(3)\rfloor \mid m\in \Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (since $\log_2(3)$ is irrational) and as such for any $\epsilon$ you can find $n,m$ so that $|n- m\log_2(3)| ≤ \log_2(5) + \epsilon$, implying that $5\cdot 2^{-\epsilon}≤\frac{2^n}{3^m} ≤ 5\cdot 2^\epsilon$, giving that you can approximate the point $5$ arbitrarily well.

Comment: 2nd paragraph (apart from first sentence) - lightbulb moment, thank-you.  So is this correct; since $2^m3^n$ is dense in $\Bbb R^+$ we can construct a sequence converging to any element of $\Bbb R^+$?

Comment: "This is not true" - which is not true?  First paragraph?  Or "$X,d$ is a metric space"?

Comment: The statement that $A$ is complete, or respectively that $\varphi(A)$ is complete, is not true. And yes, the argument showing that $5$ is a limit point can be adapted to show that $\{2^m3^n\mid n,m\in\Bbb Z\}$ is dense in $\Bbb R_{≥0}$, hence you can find a sequence approximating any point in $\Bbb R_{≥0}$.